# json serialize serializer instance

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to return some useful information after POST to my api. I have

```
# views.py
from .serializers import FlagInstanceSerializer

SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def flag(self, request, pk=None):
        some_model = self.get_object()
        flag_instance = flaggit.utils.flag(some_model, user=request.user, ip=None, comment=None)
        serializer = FlagInstanceSerializer(data=flag_instance)
        serializer.is_valid()
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

model

```
# models.py
class FlagInstance(models.Model):
    flag = models.ForeignKey(Flag, related_name='flags', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    flag_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=FLAG_TYPES, default=1)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s: %s' % (self.user, self.flag.content_object)
```

serializer

```
# serializers.py
from flaggit.models import FlagInstance

class FlagInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FlagInstance
        fields = '__all__'
```

The [rest docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer) show the following sanity check.

```
In [1]: from polls.serializers import FlagInstanceSerializer

In [2]: serializer = FlagInstanceSerializer()

In [3]: print(repr(serializer))
FlagInstanceSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    ip = IPAddressField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    datetime = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    flag_type = ChoiceField(choices=((1, 'Inappropriate'), (2, 'Move To Jobs'), (3, 'Move To Events'), (4, 'Move To Promotions')), required=False, validators=[<django.core.validators.MinValueValidator object>, <django.core.validators.MaxValueValidator object>])
    comment = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, required=False, style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})                                                                                            
    flag = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Flag.objects.all())
    user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)
```

The api responds with `{}`. I would like the api to respond with a json representation of a FlagInstance object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually put an instance "into" the serializer to serialize the values into JSON.  You are currently modifying a property that is used to deserialize the data into python objects.

Change your viewset method to this, replacing `data` with `instance`:

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def flag(self, request, pk=None):
        some_model = self.get_object()
        flag_instance = flaggit.utils.flag(some_model, user=request.user, ip=None, comment=None)
        serializer = FlagInstanceSerializer(instance=flag_instance)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```